# Permission denied when copy a file into a network hard disk folder (Raspbian)

Tags: raspbian

I have a NTFS format hard disk connected by usb to router livebox,

I have a raspberry pi with Raspbian installed.

I try to mount a folder from HD to folder inside raspberry pi

create local folder in user home /home/pi

```
mkdir mySharedFolder

drwxr-xr-x 2 pi   pi   4096 Oct 31 17:10 mySharedFolder
```

mount the folder

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o vers=1.0,_netdev,username=pi,password=mypassword,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 //192.168.1.1/discosUSB/WDElements_10B8/Elements/hdFolder /home/pi/mySharedFolder

ls -la
drwxrwxrwx 2 pi   pi      0 Oct 31 17:20 mySharedFolder
```

It mounts correctly because I can see the files and directories

```
ls -la mySharedFolder/

-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi    5 Oct 31 17:17 file.txt
drwxrwxrwx 2 pi pi    0 Oct 31 17:18 folder1

df -h
Filesystem                                                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root                                                   14G  1.4G   12G  11% /
devtmpfs                                                   213M     0  213M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                      217M  3.1M  214M   2% /run
tmpfs                                                      217M     0  217M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                                                       44M     0   44M   0% /run/user/1000
//192.168.1.1/discosUSB/WDElements_10B8/Elements/hdFolder  8.0G  2.5G  5.5G  32% /home/pi/mySharedFolder
```

Too I can open file.txt

```
cat mySharedFolder/file.txt
Hello
```

But I can't copy files to the directory:

```
 sudo cp a.jpg mySharedFolder/
 cp: error writing 'mySharedFolder/a.jpg': Permission denied
```

If I list content directory, I can see a.jpg file created whith 0 bytes

```
ls -la mySharedFolder/

-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi    0 Oct 31 17:32 a.jpg
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi    5 Oct 31 17:17 file.txt
drwxrwxrwx 2 pi pi    0 Oct 31 17:18 folder1
```

Using Android ES File Explorer I can see the folder and I can copy, delete, create files in hard disk share folder without problems

Additional info

```
sudo smbclient -L //192.168.1.1

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
cli_rpc_pipe_open_noauth: rpc_pipe_bind for pipe srvsvc failed with error NT_STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL
        discosUSB       Disk      Share Folder
        IPC$            IPC       Remote Inter Process Communication
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.

        Server               Comment
        ---------            -------

        Workgroup            Master
        ---------            -------
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: can you post the permissions of the `a.jpg` file. While you are using `sudo` (no password proimpt?) maybe It is somehow possible that you do not have read permissions on that file. Just checked by creating an `a1.jpg` file with execute permissions only with : `touch a1.jpg && chmod 111 a1.jpg && chown user1 user1 a1.jpg` as `root` in user1 directory, and then trying to copy it as that user1 within the user tree and got the same permission denied error, even though user1 is set as the owner of the file (he can change permissions himself if needed but can't copy the file without doing so first).

Comment: Also, one simple test would be to enter that specific folder and trying to create a new file within it with something as simple as cat 123 > test123.txt and see if you get a permission error. Also, you should try mounting the filesystem with uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),forceuid,forcegid just to be safe, because `ntfs` mounts force root as default user. Also check the actual mount in `cat /etc/mstab`

Comment: Thanks BarBar1234. The permissions of a.jpg are -rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi    0 Oct 31 17:32 a.jpg

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a new file within the remote folder itself from the terminal?

Comment: Hi, I testing create a file inside folder `cd mySharedFolder/`  `sudo echo 123 > test123.txt` and the result is `echo  write error: Permission denied`

Also I test mount with `uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),forceuid,forcegid` 
with the same result, Permission denied when copy and creating file  Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I trie to mount a hard drive shared by samba and connected to an Android TV box.

I have been able to mount it and it allows me to copy, create files without problems. I guess it's a livebox router permissions issue